# Spark session value not updating

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am setting spark session value using below code

```
    spark = (SparkSession
                        .builder
                        .appName('LoadDev1')
                        #.config("spark.master","local[2]")
                        .config("spark.master","yarn")
                        .config("spark.yarn.queue","uldp")
                        .config("spark.tez.queue","uldp")
                        .config("spark.executor.instances","5")
                        .enableHiveSupport()
                        .getOrCreate()
                  )
           return spark

spark-submit --jars /app/spark3.3.1/jars/iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12-1.1.0.jar  --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100 --conf spark.hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false --py-files 
/home/path/SparkFactory_iceberg1.py
```

But when I print the values inside my program for example spark.executor.instances value = 10 although I can see that appname is changing if I am changing the config file which make me believe that this config file is indeed read but somehow values are overwritten.

If I provide the value using --conf it is reflected but I want to use config file rather than --conf.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark-submit` is a completely separate application than the session you create at the top, so you need to pass those configs into the `spark-submit` command, and you can create a [properties-file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#loading-configuration-from-a-file) which will override the default spark config at `conf/spark-defaults.conf` with the configs like this:

app.conf

```
spark.master yarn
spark.yarn.queue uldp
spark.tez.queue uldp
spark.executor.instances 5
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 100
spark.hive.vectorized.execution.enabled false
```

```bash
$ spark-submit \
    --properties-file <PATH>/app.conf \
    --jars /app/spark3.3.1/jars/iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12-1.1.0.jar \
    --py-files /home/path/SparkFactory_iceberg1.py \
    /home/path/main.py
```

Comment: thanks for your response but some of the parameters such as spark.yarn.queue is set to uldp but when I try to change it in the sparkFactory.py file it is not reflecting and this is not a default value so what are you saying does not make sense completelt.

Comment: Not sure what is the `sparkFactory.py` but if this change is at runtime then I think it won't reflect since the `spark.yarn.queue` should be specified before submitting the job so it can select the correct yarn queue to run on

Comment: sparkFactory.py is specified at the time time of spark-submit using --py-files and it contains all the config details which I have specified in the code block. I can see the correct value set of spark.yarn.queue specified in sparkFactory.py but when I am trying to change this it is not reflecting. Previously it was working perfectly fine atleast till 3.0.2 spark but seems now that value is overwritten or some where cached which is used.

Comment: I'd recommend trying out adding a separate config file and using the `--properties-file` instead of setting the configs in the application python code itself, properties like `spark.yarn.queue` needs to be set before submitting the application so it can run on the correct yarn queue

Comment: surely I will try your recommendation but I dont know why all of sudden things have changed while I am using this config from lot of time, inly thing that have changed is spark version from 3.0.2 to 3.3.1.

Comment: I have tried app.conf but behaviour is very strange. example app.name I am giving as LoadDev2 in conf file but still its taking app.name as LoadDev1, shuffle partition value it is taking from app.conf but spark.executor.instances is showing as 10 although in conf file I have given the value of 5. It seems value is being overwritten, any reason for that ?

Comment: Do you still override the values at the `SparkFactory.py`?

Comment: I have commented most of the values including app.name, executor instances etc.

Comment: I think the app name is very unique so there must be some other location that specifies the `LoadDev1`, or maybe you are still submitting the old files?

Comment: app.name was just an example even executor instances is also kind of defaulting to 10 even though I have provided the value of 5 in app.conf and same was the issue before when I was using sparkFactory.py. even for app.name I know no one is using the system currently so it should show LoadDev2. Is there any way I can know from where spark session values are getting picked ?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to get the source of the configs. but what I meant by looking at the app.name is that the name is unique so you can trace all the files you have to check if anywhere in the code sets this property

Comment: Just to double check also the app name you can set it using `spark.app.name` not `app.name`